# Ambiguous use of 'mutableCopy()' Swift3

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to update Swift 3 and I got the following error :

```
Ambiguous use of 'mutableCopy()'
```

Before update to swift 3. It runs well.

Swift 2.3

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("listsavednews")?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

Swift 3.0

```
(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "listsavednews")? as AnyObject).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

I found that mutableCopy in Swift3 return Any that doesnt have method mutableCopy() so that it needs to cast to AnyObject.

Any helps thanks.

I dont know why I can't comment.

Thanks all, I'll be using :

```
UserDefaults.standard.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "listsavednews")
```

Comment: What kind of object are you really getting from `UserDefaults`? Why are you using `mutableCopy` in Swift 3?

Comment: try using the appropriate method `var array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "listsavednews")` and use Swift native array type

Answer (score 3):

`mutableCopy` is an Objective-C method from `NSObject`. There's little reason to use it in Swift 3.

Since you are dealing with `UserDefaults` and `mutableCopy`, you must be dealing with either an array or dictionary. Or it could be a string.

The proper way to do this in Swift 3 is to use the proper `UserDefaults` method to get an array or dictionary. And assign the result to a `var`. That combination will give you a mutable array or mutable dictionary.

```
var someArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "somekey")
```

or:

```
var someDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "somekey")
```

In the two above cases, you end up with an optional since there might not be any data for the given key. And you also get a non-specific array or dictionary which isn't ideal. It would be better to cast the result to the appropriate type.

Let's say you have an array of strings and you want an empty array if there is nothing currently in user defaults. You can then do:

```
var someArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "somekey" as? [String]) ?? []
```

Adjust as necessary if the array contains something other than `String`.

If you actually have a dictionary, the code would be similar.

```
var someDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "somekey") as? [String:String] ?? [:]
```

If your original object is just a string, then you could do:

```
var someString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "somekey") ?? ""
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. Updated.