# Swift 3 : Ambiguous use of mutablecopy

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification

When i migrated the code from swift 2.3 to 3.0, its throwing an error as below:
let dictionary = (self.testArray!.object(at: i) as AnyObject).mutableCopy()
How to resolve this issue.

Comment: You are getting dictionary so, Make it as var dictionary = self.testArray!.object(at: i) as Dictionary<string,AnyObject>

Comment: @Gagan_iOS, how about mutable copy?

Comment: You are in Swift which is value typw :) so var is sufficient for mutable

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43132092/3901620

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `mutableCopy` in Swift. The `var` keyword makes objects mutable

```
var dictionary = self.testArray![i] as! [String:Any]
```

And don't use Foundation collection types (`NSArray` / `NSDictionary`) in Swift either.
Use native types.